# How get values in XPages to generate a report?

Tags: report, lotus-notes, xpages

I want to get the values ​​of one of my fields XPage to filter these values ​​and generate a report taking a view of the values ​​according to the selected values ​​in my XPage.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
document1.getItemValueString("NameField");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but regarding XPages and Report Generating I did a video on my NotesIn9 screencast with an example.  http://notesin9.com/index.php/2011/07/14/notesin9-029-combine-url-parameters-with-excel-exporting/

There is also an example at XPagesCheatSheet.com on the first CheatSheet.